# Testing stored procedure scalability

Tags: sql-server, performance, testing, scalability, performance-testing

I have an email application that will be called upon to deliver to the UI the number of new messages for a given user on each page load. I have a few variations of things I am testing on the DB level but all are abstracted by the stored proc call.

I'm trying to slam the DB to see what the breaking point (# of requests per second) would be.

In a nutshell, I have a table such as this userId, newMsgCount with a clustered index on userId. SQL should be able to server hundreds or thousands of these responses per second. I think the laggard is my .NET app.

How can I make this a good test to achieve the test results based on SQL performance?

Is there a tool for this that i can give it a stored proc name and param for it to pund my  DB?

I want to see if the DB can return a min. of 250 responses per second.

Answer (score 13):

SQLQueryStress is a great tool for small scale concurrency testing but it isn't really up to the job of load testing. A surprisingly little known toolset is available for free, from Microsoft, that can cope with most SQL Server stress testing scenarios, the [RML Utilities](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944837).

A very brief outline of the tools:

- **ReadTrace** converts Profiler traces from .trc files to .rml (Replay Markup Language).
- **OStress** is used to replay .rml and .sql files against a server.
- **ORCA** (OStress Replay Control Agent) co-ordinates replay across distributed instances of OStress.
- **Reporter** provides performance analysis reports.

There is an excellent fast start article from the SQLCat team which includes a sample database and workloads, [Precision Performance for Microsoft SQL Server using RML Utilities 9.0](https://web.archive.org/web/20120513103036/http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2008/02/01/precision-performance-for-microsoft-sql-server-using-rml-utilities-9-0.aspx)

You have the option of either Profiling activity for replay or, possibly more appropriate in your scenario, hand cranking a set of .sql scripts that you then replay via OStress and ORCA.

Great tools for both load testing and investigating performance issues.

Answer (score 6):

One tool you can use is [SQLQueryStress](https://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/p/sqlquerystress/9n46qj5sbgkb). For a quick start provide: the stored procedure the iterations and the number of threads. Then start the stress testing. Metrics like CPU seconds, logical reads, etc... will be shown.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you are a .NET developer. One way would be to write a small application that uses multithreading and have just a set amount of concurrent hits to the database and the stored procedure. Run a trace while this is happening.

Write the application code to increment the amount of concurrent threads on a specific interval if you want to automatically increase the load on SQL Server.

That's the way I would go about it.