# How to stress test a SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, mysql, performance, performance-testing

I've been tasked to stress test our MSSQL Server and MySQL Server. I would like to know if there are any tools or scripts which I could use on our current systems and the new system to compare performance?

I would like to measure read / write to disk and processor performance. Anything else that may be useful would be great as well.

Thanks!

Comment: For SQL Server, I'm frequently mentioning the RML tools which are discussed in http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/testing-stored-procedure-scalability/5839#5839.

Comment: Thanks for the post. Great set of tools for MSSQL. I'll have to give it a shot and see what I can come up with. This actually helps in our environment as I can re-create user activity with our database.

That said, I also found SQLIOSim from Microsoft. It doesn't quite test the DB but it does test the IO of the system which the DB lives on.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231619

Comment: Careful with SQLIOSIM, it's intended to test IO stability rather than capability http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/04/05/sqliosim-is-not-an-i-o-performance-tuning-tool.aspx. SQLIO is the tool you want instead.

Comment: Please also look at our DTM DB Stress tool (www.sqledit.com/stress). It was designed for exact requested purpose.

Comment: JMeter comes to mind, should work for both (you could even run the same/identical if you design them properly)

Answer (score 10):

Quest offers a free version of their Benchmark Factory that works for Oracle, SQL Server, and MySQL:

http://www.quest.com/benchmark-factory/

I recorded a video on getting started with it back when I worked for Quest:

http://www.toadworld.com/Videos/tabid/831/TID/559/cid/161/Default.aspx

You can call your own stored procs, replay traces, run TPC benchmark scripts, and more.  It's not exactly easy to use, though - thus the video.

Answer (score 4):

For MySQL, there's the official [benchmark suite](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-benchmarks.html). Alternatively a tool like [sysbench](http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/). I'm currently in the process of testing out sysbench, but I've been [having some trouble](https://serverfault.com/questions/323264/sysbench-errors-out-on-mysql-oltp-test)!

Answer (score 2):

The defacto standard for comparing one database solution to another is the TPC-C benchmark.   The latest definition of this benchmark can be downloaded from http://www.tpc.org/tpcc/default.asp along with existing benchmark result sets.

While it is unlikely you will run the full TPC-C at your location, the test definition should provide the foundation for developing a set of internal benchmarks designed to identify performance differences on a reference set of hardware with respect to your organization's specific requirements for transactional throughput.

Make sure you download the cost of ownership documentation as well, for this can provide a standardized method for evaluating the two solutions.