# How do you generate large OLTP and reporting workloads?

Tags: sql-server, scalability, learning, vldb

My current skillset lies towards plain vanilla data warehousing, with < 20k users, our setups are rather simple..

I am looking for ways to enhance my technical skills, however, as much theory as I read, I'm struggling to figure out how I can actually generate workloads of 100k+ transactions/second  , or 10k users hitting a report from different parts of the world.

How do people normally gain expertise in large scale database systems outside of what they do at work?  (I have a MSDN subscription, so $150/month on Azure to play with)

Comment: Google HammerDB, SQLQueryStress, SQLIOSIM

Comment: [Replay Markup Language (RML) Utilities for SQL Server](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5839/2374)

Answer (score 0):

I think the [TPC-H benchmark](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/default.asp) (or TPC-DS) might be a good start. The council publishes the tool to generate data and the workload.