# mongodb read write locks

Tags: performance, mongodb, locking, scalability

I'm currently investigating the possibility of using mongodb. This would contain the a collection of 100million+ documents. I need a process that will be constantly running deleting documents older than some expiry data. I will have new documents constantly going into this. I will also have big updates occuring that may need to update X million document to change the expiry date because a tenant has changed their retention policy. At the same time a front end will be reading this data to show a report which can be filtered.

Reading the mongodb documentation it looks like when I do a write I'll be locking out the reads until the writes have completed. Is there a better way to prevent the expiry of old documents and updating of expiry dates blocking the front ended display this data in a report?

Comment: It's possibility of duplicate thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638744/mongodb-read-write-locks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing stored procedure scalability](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/testing-stored-procedure-scalability)

Answer (score 1):

> I need a process that will be constantly running deleting documents
>   older than some expiry data.

This you can do it by creating a Time to live(TTL) on the expiration date. [TTL indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) are special single-field indexes that MongoDB can use to automatically remove documents from a collection after a certain amount of time or at a specific clock time.

> Reading the MongoDB documentation it looks like when I do a write I'll
>   be locking out the reads until the writes have completed.

MongoDB wired tiger storage engine gives document level [locking](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/concurrency/#what-type-of-locking-does-mongodb-use). So, in this case, only the documents that are being updated/inserted will be locked. Other documents are available to read.